# SocketException Error on launching ProM Lite 1.3

Tags: java, socketexception, process-mining

After starting the proM application by running the ProMLite13.sh file I am getting the following error -

```
Started package manager session
Downloading: ApacheUtils-6.9.122
I/O Exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
An error has occurred. Please select OK to continue.
```

I have the following java version installed -

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```